# ConcurrentHashMap: what's the point in locking updates only?

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, concurrency, locking

I always thought that `ConcurrentHashMap` and similar classes (which maintain synchronized updates and don't synchronize reads) did a very useful and intuitive thing: they did not lock reads and lock all functionality on updates. And a strategy like that does keep all things consistent.

But I read the documentation carefully, and opened the implementation of `ConcurrentHashMap`, and as I understand now, it *does not* block reads when another thread is performing updates. And if one thread starts doing `putAll(hugeCollection)` and another thread repeats `contains(theSameObjectForAllCalls)` at the same time then it's more then likely that the second thread gets different results while `putAll` is still working.

Here is the related part from the docs:

> For aggregate operations such as
>   putAll and clear, concurrent
>   retrievals may reflect insertion or
>   removal of only some entries.

Another interesting thing is that:

> Retrievals reflect the results of the
>   most recently completed update
>   operations holding upon their onset.

This works not due to some locking, but because a new object is first being added and only after that objects counter is incremented and the object becomes *visible* for read operations.

So, what's the whole point of locking updates?

Answer (score 4):

Brian Goetz explained the working in an [article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp08223/#3.0) at developer works. That should help out.

Comment: Thank goodness for Brian and Doug, their books have rescued me many a time in sailing the concurrency high seas.

Answer (score 4):

These classes give you additional control of tradeoffs around concurrency versus consistency.  If what you really want is to have atomic, consistent reads, then get yourself a synchronized hashmap.  However, if you need more concurrency, you can get a ConcurrentHashMap, so long as you're aware that reads will get an accurate picture of what the map looked like at some point, just not necessarily *now*.

The tradeoff is that you have to think harder about the consistency of the data, but your app can have much much greater concurrency.

Comment: aye, I tend to think of it as accuracy vs. performance in that way.